# C# Fazer tecla Enter pular para tanto campo textBox ou comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Como eu posso fazer em uma função, que quando a pessoa der enter , ele pule para o campo de baixo , que pode ser tanto um combobox quanto um textbox?

Atualmente tenho essa função , mais ela pula para o último textbox , fazendo assim fazer login, sem passar pelos combobox primeiro

```
public void pulaProxCampo(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)) 
    {
       this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
    }
}
```

Da para fazer ou preciso fazer uma validação de campos para ver se estão vazios?

Comment: Eu sempre acho melhor ensinar os usuários a usar a tecla tab

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução muito comum é fazer o Enter agir como Tab. Pra funcionar corretamente vai depender da ordem de tabulação dos controles. E coloque `TabStop` para false nos que não devem receber foco.

```
public void pulaProxCampo(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)) 
    {
       SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está correto e funcional. O problema aí é que seus controles no *container* não estão com o `TabOrder` correto.

Então, **troque a propriedade `TabOrder` dos seu controles para seguir a ordem desejada.**

Outro ponto importante é que o código acima passa por todos os elementos, mesmo os que tem `TabStop` definida como `false`. Isso vai fazer com que o <kbd>Tab</kbd> e o <kbd>Enter</kbd> tenham comportamentos diferentes.

O método [`SelectNextControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) recebe 5 parâmetros, sendo eles

1. **`Control ctrl`**: O controle pelo qual a busca vai iniciar.
2. **`bool forward`**: Define a se a busca vai próximo controle (`true`) ou para o anterior (`false`)
3. **`bool tabStopOnly`**: Se essa propriedade for `true` os controles com `TabStop = false` serão ignorados, `false` pro caso contrário.
4. **`nested`**: Define se devem ser selecionados os controles filhos. Exemplo: Existe um `TextBox` e `DataGridView`; se esta propriedade for definida como `true` as células do `DataGridView` também serão selecionadas.
5. **`wrap`**: Define se a busca recomeça ao chegar no último controle do *container*.

Answer (score 1):

Pode saltar de forma explicita para um determinado *control* usando o método [Focus()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx) desse *control*.

```
public void pulaProxCampo(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)) 
    {
        if(deveSaltarParaTextBox)
        {
            textBox.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            combobox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Use esta abordagem apenas se o salto não seguir o percurso definido pelo TabOrder.